# How to add channel if Replication is running?

Tags: couchbase-lite

I am working with dynamic channels for Replication pull at couchbase lite.
If i use single replication object, i need to stop first,then start. That's problem if pull is running . How to solve this problem .How i will know is pull running . Any way to create multiple object of Replication?

Comment: Why do you need to stop the replication?  Are you filtering replications by channel?  Otherwise you shouldn't need to.  What's the problem with stopping a replication while it's running?  You can have more than one replication object, but I would make sure you need them.

Comment: i got solution that restart with continue both channels . no need to stop , just change setting and  restart pull .

Answer (score 0):

Use a Replication ChangeListener.  Here's an example that monitors for a replication stopping.

```
public class DBHelper implements Replication.ChangeListener {
  private boolean replicationActive = false;
  private List stateListeners = new ArrayList<>();
  ...

  public interface ReplicationStateListener {
    void onChange(boolean isActive);
  }

  public void startReplication(URL gateway, boolean continuous) {
    ...

    pushReplication.addChangeListener(this);
    pushReplication.start();
  }

  public void stopReplication() {
    ...
  }

  public void addReplicationStateListener(ReplicationStateListener listener) {
    stateListeners.add(listener);
  }

  public void removeReplicationStateListener(ReplicationStateListener listener) {
    stateListeners.remove(listener);
  }

  // Replication.ChangeListener
  @Override
  public void changed(Replication.ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
    if (changeEvent.getError() != null) {
      Throwable lastError = changeEvent.getError();

      // React to the error

      return;
    }

    if (changeEvent.getTransition() == null) return;

    ReplicationState dest = changeEvent.getTransition().getDestination();

    replicationActive = ((dest == ReplicationState.STOPPING || dest == ReplicationState.STOPPED) ? false : true);

    stateListeners.forEach(listener -> listener.onChange(replicationActive));
  }
}
```

You can read more details here: https://blog.couchbase.com/determining-status-replication-couchbase-lite/